# 列データから正規表現で取り出したデータを、新しい列に書き込むには？

Tags: python, pandas

次のようなデータフレームdfで、

a
　１   abc def
　２   123 567
　３   qqq eee

a列のデータに正規表現で取り出したデータを、あらたな列に加える

a          b
　１   abc def     def
　２   123 567     567
　３   qqq eee     eee

には、どうすればいいですか？

df['b']=正規表現関数(df['a']) でははねられました。

Comment: map を使う方法などを。`df['b'] = map(lambda x: re.search(r"(.{3})$", x).group(0), df['a'])`

Comment: metropolis  さま、ありがとうございます。mapの使い方を調べてみます。

Comment: 試したところ、df[b]の内容は列すべて、<map object at 0x000002B5BFD93F60>になっています。

Comment: df['b'] = df['a'].map(lambda x: re.search(r"(.{3})$", x).group(0)) でも結果は同じです。

Comment: 列をSeriesとして切り出し、mapを適用した後、DataFrameにマージすれば、出来ました。ほかにうまい方法は、ありませんか？

Comment: ああ、python3 を使っているのですね。python2 だと思っていました。

Comment: python3 の場合は、`df['b'] = list(map(lambda x: re.search(r"(.{3})$", x).group(0), df['a']))` となります。

Answer (score 1):

Series a に対してstr.extractで値を切り出して、結果を新しい列bに代入しました。

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['abc def'],['123 567'], ['qqq eee']], columns=['a'])
>>> df
         a
0  abc def
1  123 567
2  qqq eee
>>> df['a'].str.extract(r'(.{3})$', expand=True)
     0
0  def
1  567
2  eee
>>> df['b'] = df['a'].str.extract(r'(.{3})$', expand=False)
>>> df
         a    b
0  abc def  def
1  123 567  567
2  qqq eee  eee
```