# pandasのDataFrameに対する演算

Tags: python, python3, pandas

Pythonでpandasの練習をしています。CSVから `read_csv()` でDataFrameを作成し、その特定の列に対して演算を行おうと思っています。例えばこんな感じです。

```
　　A
1  12A
2  14A
3  55B    
4  99F
```

A列に対して、ある処理 `func()` を行いその結果を新しい列として追加したいと思っています。どのように記載するのが良いのでしょうか？
`pandas.DataFrame.append()` かなと思いながら、使い方がよくわかりませんでした。

Comment: この記事とか参考になりそうです。[Create a new column in Pandas DataFrame based on the existing columns](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-new-column-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-the-existing-columns/), [Pandas の特定の条件に基づいて DataFrame 列を作成する方法](https://www.delftstack.com/ja/howto/python-pandas/how-to-create-dataframe-column-based-on-given-condition-in-pandas/) 実際に何をしたいかを具体的に記述すると、的確な助言や回答が得られるでしょう。

Comment: A列は文字列ですよね？文字列に対する「演算」とは具体的には何でしょうか？

Comment: すいません、具体的には文字列にsplitをしたかったんです。
こんかいの例ではやりようがないですが '12:36'のような字列を 12と36に分けて計算をしようかなと思っておりました。df['A']は class 'pandas.core.series.Series'でありsplitはできませんでした。

Comment: 例えば時刻を分割するならこんな記事が参考になるでしょう。[How to extract hour, minute and second from Series filled with datetime.time values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49298488/9014308) 単に分割するだけなら、こちらの記事など。[How to split a dataframe string column into two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14745022/9014308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seriesを操作する関数は複数ありますので、適切な関数を用いるのがよろしいかと存じます。
下記はスタックオーバーフローに出てきた関数ごとの関連質問の例です。

[split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)関連質問: [データフレーム：特定の複数の文字で列を分割したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/41678)
[map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)関連質問: [関数を適用したときにList化されないようにするには](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/68744)
[extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)関連質問: [列データから正規表現で取り出したデータを、新しい列に書き込むには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/36217)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["12A", "55B", "99F"],
                   'B': ["9:30", "14:00", "23:59"]})

def func(value):
    # 16進数文字列を10進数に変換する
    return int(value, 16)

# B列をsplitで":"ごとに分割する
df_splitted = df['B'].str.split(":", expand = True)
df_splitted.columns = ["hour", "minute"]
print(df_splitted)

# A列にmapでfunc関数を適用する
df['map'] = df['A'].map(func)

# B列にextractで正規表現を使って:以下を抽出する
df['extract'] = df['B'].str.extract(r":(\d{1,2})$", expand = False)
print(df)
```

Comment: 大変わかりやすい説明をありがとうございました。map(func)がとても便利だと感じました。

Answer (score 0):

ある処理func()というのを仮定でランダムな数字を置いています．
appendを使うのであれば，Listをdfに追加するといいと思います．

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["12A", "55B", "99F"]})
testList = []
for i in range(len(df['A'])):
    testList.append(df['A'][i] + '%r'%(random.randrange(10)) )
df['B'] = testList
df
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。forで回す方法も考えたのですが、せっかくDataFrameなのでいっぺんにできないかなと質問させていただいた次第です。